# How to check a single number value against an array of meta_key values?

Tags: meta-query, array

There seems to be a ton of information on checking a `meta_key` against an array of `meta_values`, but I want to do the opposite.

I have a site with projects, and press reviews. When the client adds a review, they have a custom field (ACF) to select the project it relates to from a list.

I am now trying to display all press reviews that relate to a certain project, together on a page. I have the project ID, and use a query with $args to select the press reviews I want.

My current `$args`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'pressreview',
    'order'         =>  DESC,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'belongs_to_project',
            'value' => $projectID,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

The problem is, that custom field '`belongs_to_project`' returns an array with IDs. One press review can be about multiple projects, so I let the client pick multiple projects from the list in that field. A typical array will be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 210 [1] => 202 ).
```

What I want to do, is check whether the `$projectID` is in that array.

In the current setup, it sort of works: if the client selected 202 and 210 from the list, and the `$projectID` is `210`, the press review is shown. However, if the `$projectID = 20`, we get press reviews for projects `201`, `202`, `203`, etc. (since those numbers include '`20`', which is how `LIKE` works)

Is there any way I can tell this query to only check for 'whole' numbers? So that "2" would only show reviews for project `2`, and not for `201`, `202`, or any other numbers that have a 2 in them?

I've seen there is a `REGEXP` option to use instead of `LIKE`, but I can't find out how to use it in a way that it checks for only 'whole numbers'.

I've also tried '`IN`', but that doesn't work at all here.

One thing that I thought of, but don't know whether it's possible at all, is to use something like:

```
'key' => 'belongs_to_project[$i]'
```

with some kind of loop through the key values, so that `$projectID` could be checked with `'='` instead of `LIKE` against each of the values in the array of the custom field.
I've no idea if there's any such option and how it should be written.

Hope my explanation is clear enough, please let me know if I need to explain better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was that I need to compare the literal value of `$projectID`, so that `LIKE` compares an exact string instead of just numbers. To make `$projectID` literal, it needs to be wrapped in quotes.

So, I changed this line:

`'value' => $projectID,`

to:

`'value' => '"'.$projectID.'"',`

Which solves the problem.

Comment: Very good. This works because the values are stored between quotes inside the array in the db. Great simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use `IN` at `compare`
but you said this's not working.
and I notice something (please forgive me if this's a mistake ):
you write example for array

```
Array ( [0] => 210 [1] => 202 ).
```

this mean the value in array is `NUMERIC` and the Default type is 'CHAR'.
so you can try

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'pressreview',
    'order'         =>  DESC,
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => 'belongs_to_project',
            'value' => $projectID,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC'
         )
     )
);
```

Comment: I don't think I can use `'='`, because `$projectID` is not an `array`, so it can't be equal. I agree with adding `'type' => 'NUMERIC'`, but for some reason that makes the query not return any results at all. Even so, I've tried your exact solution as well to be sure, but it didn't work. I get zero results when using `NUMERIC`.

Comment: My mistake :/ , I write `=` instead of `IN` , ok. now you need to `var_dump` returned array of `belongs_to_project` without any compare to be sure what kind of array values return.

Comment: I know exactly the array it returns. and it's numeric. However, I've found the solution (with outside help!), will post the answer in a few minutes.